# How to set django HttpResponse content after create？

Tags: python, django

In flask ,we can use response.set_data(r),  but how to do this in Django?

```
response = HttpResponse(text)
```

Comment: Err, like that?

Comment: what do you mean

Comment: You use exactly the code you have given.

Answer (score 0):

If you set `Content-Length` in previous code, you need reset `Content-Length`, otherwise:

> ERR_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH

... will occur.

```
response.content='11112222'
# response['Content-Length'] = len(response.content)
```